# Supersonic getting started - what is Google Advertising ID

Tags: android, supersonic, google-advertising-id

I am trying to integrate supersonic, and stuck on their requrenment -

> "Integrate Google Play Services The Supersonic SDK requires access to
>   the Google Advertising ID in order to operate properly. See this guide
>   on how to integrate Google Play Services. Note: Make sure you are
>   using the latest Google Play Services version. Prior versions might
>   not work on devices using Lollipop (API 21)."

That is all info, they said abot their needs. I added 
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0 to my gradle file, and I am able to receive my Advertise id, but I am not sure, is that what i need

```
AdvertisingIdClient.Info info = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(App.getContext());
```

Please, if anyone integrated supersonic on android, help me to make it work, and explain what does they mean by

> The Supersonic SDK requires access to the Google Advertising ID

Comment: If you aren't displaying ads yourself, then I don't understand why that is needed, but your advertising id is a unique identifer for your phone to serve you advertisements. That's Google's primary business model, advertising

Answer (score 0):

Google Advertising ID is only an identification number.
[Page link](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html)

I think Supersonic leans this identifier because it is unique and therefore are unable to distinguish the installations.

I also read somewhere that if you do not use what you could also use a incremetale variable.
(For example, the primary key in a database that is automatically increments)

Answer (score 0):

> The advertising ID is a user-specific, unique, resettable ID for advertising, provided by Google Play services. It gives users better controls and provides developers with a simple, standard system to continue to monetize your apps. It is an anonymous identifier for advertising purposes and enables users to reset their identifier or opt out of interest-based ads within Google Play apps.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html)

As I stated in the comments, though, I would immediately be hesitant to anything that explicitly requires something that serves ads or reads your ad preferences. I guess that's better than the alternative of not saying it's needed, but using it anyways, though.